# What are these bracketing symbols and what do they mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What do the matching "L" shapes (near `.5` and `20`) mean in this forumla?

[image: fomula with unknown symbols]

The document where I found this formula can be found here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~hcwong/Pdfs/icip02.ps

Comment: It is the "floor function", meaning the largest integer $\le$ the quantity within.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bracketing symbol means Floor (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)

The definition of Floor is $\lfloor x \rfloor$ = Largest integer less than x. This is very similar to rounding down as $\lfloor 2.3 \rfloor = \lfloor 2.999 \rfloor = 2$. However, the subtlety is that for negative numbers it acts slightly differently, as $\lfloor -1.5 \rfloor  = -2$ which might not be what you expect at first.

Answer (score 1):

Floor function: Round down to the nearest integer.