# what does this symbol mean: [] but without the top bars?

Tags: notation

What does the highlighted symbol mean?
What are the details of this method?[image]

Comment: It might refer to the [greatest integer function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are these bracketing symbols and what do they mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356472/what-are-these-bracketing-symbols-and-what-do-they-mean)

Answer (score 3):

The symbol $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ usually denotes [the floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). $\lfloor x\rfloor$  is the largest integer not greater than $x$, i.e.
$$
\lfloor x \rfloor=\max\, \{m\in\mathbb{Z}\mid m\le x\}
$$
for each $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer relates only to the first question.**

$\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function, which rounds down $x$ to nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). It's shorthand for the largest integer not greater than $T_w$.

Answer (score 0):

Tangentially, if you want to reproduce a symbol here and you don't know its Latex code, I encourage you to try [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), which is as fun as it is powerful.